# Matlab Error: Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 1

Tags: matlab, optimization

This is my code for WNS node optimization , on executing the code there is an error in bb0_de function

the error :
Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 1.

Error in test>bbo_de (line 129)
if sum(trialFitness < fitness(i, :)) == 4

Error in test (line 18)
newPopulation = bbo_de(population, fitness, nAppropriatePositions, mutationProbability,nTargetPoints,sensingRange,communicationRange,bsLocation);

129         if sum(trialFitness < fitness(i, :)) == 4

The Code:

```
% Define the problem parameters
nAppropriatePositions = 100; % number of appropriate positions
nTargetPoints = 50; % number of target points
sensingRange = 50; % sensing range of sensors
communicationRange = 100; % communication range of sensors
bsLocation = [250, 250]; % base station location
maxIteration = 100; % maximum number of iterations
mutationProbability = 0.2; % mutation probability

% Initialize the population of candidate solutions
population = 500*rand(nAppropriatePositions, 3);


for i = 1:maxIteration
    fitness = evaluateFitness(population, nTargetPoints, sensingRange, communicationRange, bsLocation,nAppropriatePositions);
    
    % Update the population using the BBO-DE algorithm
    newPopulation = bbo_de(population, fitness, nAppropriatePositions, mutationProbability,nTargetPoints,sensingRange,communicationRange,bsLocation);
    
    % Select the best solutions
    [~, idx] = sort(fitness);
    plot(newPopulation)
    population = newPopulation(idx(1:nAppropriatePositions), :);
end



% Define the objective functions
function [f1, f2, f3, f4] = evaluateObjectiveFunctions(positions, nTargetPoints, sensingRange, communicationRange, bsLocation,nAppropriatePositions)
    

    % Objective function 1: maximize the coverage of target points by sensors
    coveredPoints = zeros(nTargetPoints, 1);
    for i = 1:nTargetPoints
        for j = 1:size(positions, 1)
            distance = norm(positions(j, 1:2) - [i, i]);
            if distance <= sensingRange
                coveredPoints(i) = 1;
                break;
            end
        end
    end
    f1 = sum(coveredPoints) / nTargetPoints;

    % Objective function 2: minimize the overlap between sensors
    overlap = 0;
    for i = 1:size(positions, 1)
        for j = i+1:size(positions, 1)
            distance = norm(positions(i, 1:2) - positions(j, 1:2));
            if distance <= sensingRange*2
                overlap = overlap + (sensingRange*2 - distance);
            end
        end
    end
    f2 = overlap / nAppropriatePositions;

    % Objective function 3: maximize the connectivity of sensors
    connectivity = 0;
    for i = 1:size(positions, 1)
        for j = 1:size(positions, 1)
            distance = norm(positions(i, 1:2) - positions(j, 1:2));
            if distance <= communicationRange && i ~= j
                connectivity = connectivity + 1;
            end
        end
    end
    f3 = connectivity / (nAppropriatePositions*(nAppropriatePositions-1));

    % Objective function 4: minimize the distance between sensors and the base station
    distances = zeros(nAppropriatePositions, 1);
    for i = 1:size(positions, 1)
        distances(i) = norm(positions(i, 1:2) - bsLocation);
    end
    f4 = sum(distances) / nAppropriatePositions;
end






% Define the fitness function
function fitness = evaluateFitness(positions, nTargetPoints, sensingRange, communicationRange, bsLocation,nAppropriatePositions)
    [f1, f2, f3, f4] = evaluateObjectiveFunctions(positions, nTargetPoints, sensingRange, communicationRange, bsLocation,nAppropriatePositions);
    fitness = [f1, f2, f3, f4];
end







% Define the BBO-DE algorithm
function newPopulation = bbo_de(population, fitness, nAppropriatePositions, mutationProbability,nTargetPoints,sensingRange,communicationRange,bsLocation)
    % Define the DE parameters
    DE_crossProbability = 0.8; % crossover probability
    DE_scaleFactor = 0.9; % scale factor

    % Generate the initial population using BBO
    migrationRate = 0.01; % migration rate
    migrationSize = round(migrationRate * nAppropriatePositions); % migration size
    migrationDestinations = randperm(nAppropriatePositions, migrationSize); % migration destinations
    migrationSources = randperm(nAppropriatePositions, migrationSize); % migration sources
    newPopulation = population;
    for i = 1:migrationSize
        newPopulation(migrationDestinations(i), :) = population(migrationSources(i), :);
    end

    % Update the population using DE
    for i = 1:nAppropriatePositions
        % Select three random individuals
        candidates = randperm(nAppropriatePositions, 3);
        % Perform mutation
        mutated = population(candidates(1), :) + DE_scaleFactor * (population(candidates(2), :) - population(candidates(3), :));
        % Perform crossover
        trial = zeros(1, 3);
        for j = 1:3
            if rand() < DE_crossProbability
                trial(j) = mutated(j);
            else
                trial(j) = population(i, j);
            end
        end
        % Evaluate the fitness of the trial solution
        trialFitness = evaluateFitness(trial, nTargetPoints, sensingRange, communicationRange, bsLocation,nAppropriatePositions);
        % Perform selection
        
        if sum(trialFitness < fitness(i, :)) == 4
            newPopulation(i, :) = trial;
        end
    end
  end
```

please try to solve this problem / give a better code for it

Comment: This looks like a good time to learn how to use the debugger. It appears that the `fitness` array you pass to `bbo_de()` doesn't have `nAppropriatePositions` rows.